# Integrating COUNT into postgres query

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table titled `users` and below it is the `tracks` table and below that is the `likes` table.  The `users` table has an `id` column for the users ID and the `tracks` table has a `id` column for the track ID and a `user_ID` column for the user ID that owns the track.  The `likes` table has a `user_id` column for the user that liked the track and a `track_id` column for the track ID.  Right now my query is working perfectly, but I'd like to get a count for the number of likes a specific track ID has.

My current fetch request:

```
cur.execute('SELECT t.title, t.share, t.id, u.id, u.username, l.date_liked, '
                'FROM (tracks t INNER JOIN users u ON t.user_id = u.id)'
                'LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id = %s)'
                'l ON l.track_id = t.id ORDER BY t.id DESC', [current_user.id])
```

I'm not super savvy when it comes to Postgres. I know I need to do `SELECT COUNT(track_id) FROM likes`, but I'm not sure how to integrate it into my current query.

Playing around with Alan Samets answer below, I was able to come with this:

```
cur.execute('WITH t_count AS'
                '(SELECT tracks.id,'
                        'COUNT(*) like_count '
                            'FROM tracks '
                                 'INNER JOIN likes '
                                     'ON tracks.id = likes.track_id '
                            'GROUP BY tracks.id)'
                ', t_mylike AS'
                '(SELECT likes.track_id, likes.date_liked FROM likes WHERE likes.user_id = %s )'
                'SELECT t.title, t.share, t.id, t_count.like_count, u.id, u.username, ml.date_liked '
                     'FROM tracks t '
                          'LEFT JOIN t_count '
                              'ON t.id = t_count.id '
                          'INNER JOIN users u '
                              'ON u.id = t.user_id '
                          'LEFT JOIN t_mylike ml ON t.id = ml.track_id '
                     'ORDER BY t.id DESC', [current_user.id])
```

This is almost working perfectly, but it doesn't return correctly when the user has liked their own track.  Right now when a user likes another users track, it returns the date that was liked, but when a user likes their owner track its returning `None` - which is incorrect.

Comment: You cannot* get both the list of the likes and their count in the same query. (* technically it is possible but the resulting dataset would make no sense)

Comment: @zerkms So I would have to split it up into two queries?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM likes WHERE user_id = %s` is this the line thats getting the list that you are referring to?

Comment: The whole query returns a list of likes

Comment: Are you sure?  I believe its returning a list of tracks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that PostgreSQL supports common table expressions. I assume that the query that you're writing is to drive a UI component and that you want to show the track information, the date that the current user liked the track alongwith the count of total likes.

```
WITH t_count AS 
(
     SELECT tracks.id
     ,      COUNT(*) like_count
            FROM tracks
                 INNER JOIN likes
                     ON tracks.id = likes.track_id
            GROUP BY tracks.id
)
SELECT t.title, t.share, t.id, t_count.like_count, u.id, u.username, l.date_liked
     FROM tracks t
          INNER JOIN t_count
              ON t.id = t_count.id
          INNER JOIN users u
              ON u.id = t.user_id
          LEFT JOIN likes l
              ON u.id = likes.user_id
     WHERE user_id = %s
     ORDER BY ...
```

Comment: Yup your description is spot on.  Not sure I understand the answer though.  Can you explain whats happening here?

Comment: I had to make some corrections to your answer to get it working. It looks like it returns `1L`.  Whats the `L` for?

Comment: Research "Common Table Expressions." In this case, they work like VIEWs that exist for a single query. Much of what's on the web explains them in the context of hierarchical queries, but you can use them easily in the same way that you would use a subquery, but with better readability. There are a couple other things that "smell" a bit with your example that you should probably look into. I don't know what language you're using, but you should probably be using parameters to call your statement, and filtering/WHERE expressions should probably be placed outside of your subqueries.

Comment: This was almost working.  I had to make some tweaks.

Comment: @Brosef: see the tutorial in the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html